# PHP json_encode scientific format

Tags: php, json

I am trying to encode the number 17342846 but every time i get 1.7342846e+07 instead of the int format. i am using

```
 $var = 17342846;
 json_encode((int)$var);
```

in php trying to get it to work but still no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not telling us everything. If I run just what you showed us I get the integer and not the scientific representation

Comment: I can't reproduce it, either.

Comment: What's the value of `PHP_INT_MAX` on your system?

Comment: I am running 32bit PHP5.6.15 and `PHP_INT_MAX` is `2147483647` Ditto in PHP7.0.2 and PHP5.5

Comment: the value comes from the db but when i dump it it says (int). the PHP_INT_MAX is WAAAAY bigger than that number

Comment: try to make it to be json_encode((float)$var); i think you have problem with your PHP int.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that these are the same number, just different representations? Also, what's the reason for the `(int)` cast? That said, I can't reproduce that behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

just encode it as string format then convert it later.

```
json_encode($var + '');
```